# AFNetworking for large image

Tags: image, afnetworking

I am using my AFNetworking in my project. And I need to use it for some large image. About 4MB . When I created a imageview and use setImageWithURLRequest.
It always return failure block With this error
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)

Any idea for using AFNetworking for downloading large image?

Comment: With smaller image, does it work?
Error 999 seems to meant that your request got cancelled.

Comment: With smaller image , it works, but no idea the reason of cancelling my request